# Quarkus grpc is throwing start up error: Unable to start the gRPC server: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client, quarkus-reactive, quarkus-grpc

I am trying to start the grpc server with the property

`quarkus.grpc.server.use-separate-server=true`

in that case, i am getting the below error during server start up

```
2023-01-19 13:12:51,762 WARN  [io.qua.grp.run.GrpcServerRecorder] (main) Using legacy gRPC support, with separate new HTTP server instance. Switch to single HTTP server instance usage with quarkus.grpc.server.use-separate-server=false property
2023-01-19 13:12:51,824 INFO  [io.qua.grp.run.GrpcServerRecorder] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) Registering gRPC reflection service
2023-01-19 13:12:51,934 ERROR [io.qua.grp.run.GrpcServerRecorder] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) Unable to start the gRPC server: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:149)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:157)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.netBind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:330)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:141)
```

But when I start the grpc server with property

```
quarkus.grpc.server.use-separate-server=false
```

the grpc server starts but the client is not able to  access the server
I am getting the below error on the client side

```
13:54:28 ERROR line=111 traceId=, parentId=, spanId=, sampled= [qu.ms.of.OfferResource] (executor-thread-0) Exception: UNAVAILABLE: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: delayed connect error: 111: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: delayed connect error: 111
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:271)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:252)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:165)
```

How do we overcome this issue?